# how to call a middlaware when calling a route in controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, backend, middleware

this is where I need middlware

```
 public function getFileAttribute()
{
    return route('backend.file_url', [
        'path' => $this->attributes['attachment'],
    ]);
}
```

this is my route

```
    Route::get('file-url', 'FileController@getFileUrl')->name('file_url');
```

I want to use middlaware Like this but not in web.php or api.php
I need it in controller

```
    Route::get('/download/{ticket}', 'TicketController@downloadPicture')->name('download')->middleware(['can:download,ticket']);
```

Comment: Why do you "need it in controller"?

Comment: This is very confusing. You have a function name `getFileAttribute` a route referring to `getFileUrl` so I don't see how one relates to the other and how `ticket` relates to it

Comment: ticket doesn't relate to it , this is an example that I said . i want to call middlware in controller like second route

Comment: in getFileAttribute function ,I return that route here in this function I need middlware .and I use this route in other controller that doesn't need middlware

Comment: you are returning a string for the URL of the route and it looks like that is a model method ... not sure what middleware would have to do with that

Answer (score 1):

You can assign middleware to the actions of the Controller by registering the middleware in the constructor of the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('middleware-name')->only('someMethod');
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Controllers - Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware)